# Generating a text representation of Python's AST

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

With Clang we can do:

`clang -cc1 -ast-dump j.c`

```
TranslationUnitDecl 0x7fbcfc00f608 <<invalid sloc>> <invalid sloc>
|-TypedefDecl 0x7fbcfc00fea0 <<invalid sloc>> <invalid sloc> implicit __int128_t '__int128'
| `-BuiltinType 0x7fbcfc00fba0 '__int128'
|-TypedefDecl 0x7fbcfc00ff08 <<invalid sloc>> <invalid sloc> implicit __uint128_t 'unsigned __int128'
| `-BuiltinType 0x7fbcfc00fbc0 'unsigned __int128'
|-TypedefDecl 0x7fbcfc0101b8 <<invalid sloc>> <invalid sloc> implicit __NSConstantString 'struct __NSConstantString_tag'
| `-RecordType 0x7fbcfc00ffd0 'struct __NSConstantString_tag'
|   `-Record 0x7fbcfc00ff58 '__NSConstantString_tag'
|-TypedefDecl 0x7fbcfc010250 <<invalid sloc>> <invalid sloc> implicit __builtin_ms_va_list 'char *'
| `-PointerType 0x7fbcfc010210 'char *'
|   `-BuiltinType 0x7fbcfc00f6a0 'char'
|-TypedefDecl 0x7fbcfc0104f8 <<invalid sloc>> <invalid sloc> implicit __builtin_va_list 'struct __va_list_tag [1]'
| `-ConstantArrayType 0x7fbcfc0104a0 'struct __va_list_tag [1]' 1
|   `-RecordType 0x7fbcfc010320 'struct __va_list_tag'
|     `-Record 0x7fbcfc0102a0 '__va_list_tag'
|-FunctionDecl 0x7fbcfb844200 <j.c:3:1, line:12:1> line:3:5 main 'int ()'
| `-CompoundStmt 0x7fbcfb8447b8 <col:12, line:12:1>
|   |-DeclStmt 0x7fbcfb844350 <line:4:3, col:8>
|   | `-VarDecl 0x7fbcfb8442f0 <col:3, col:7> col:7 used e 'int'
....
```

Is there a way to do it with Python's AST?

I found astdump: https://pypi.org/project/astdump/

But it doesn't print tokens' literals:

```
>>> import astdump
>>> astdump.indented('2+3')
Module
  Expr
    BinOp
      Num
      Add
      Num
```

I need to be able to reconstruct the entire code from the AST.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Update for Python 3.9+**: The [`ast.dump`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.dump) function in the standard library now has an optional keyword argument `indent` for pretty-printing of Python ASTs. You pass either an integer for the number of spaces, or a string.

---

The [astpretty library](https://github.com/asottile/astpretty) seems to be suitable for your purpose. This library has a pretty-print function `pprint` which renders the tree structure of an AST including node types and contents in a readable format. You need to combine this with [`ast.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.parse) from the Python standard library.

The default behaviour of `pprint` is more verbose, including the line number and column offset of each node, but this can be disabled with the argument `show_offsets=False`. The usage example below is from the astpretty library's readme.

```py
>>> astpretty.pprint(ast.parse('x += 5').body[0], show_offsets=False)
AugAssign(
    target=Name(id='x', ctx=Store()),
    op=Add(),
    value=Num(n=5),
)
```

Note that if you don't need pretty-printing then the standard library's [`ast.dump`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.dump) will work. The output will be somewhat-readable but less so, since it's not indented to show the tree structure:

```py
>>> print(ast.dump(ast.parse('x += 5').body[0]))
AugAssign(target=Name(id='x', ctx=Store()), op=Add(), value=Num(n=5))
```

Comment: There's no need for a seperate module anymore. `ast.dump(...)` supports an `indent` argument for prettifying.

Answer (score 2):

A seperate library for pretty-printing isn't required anymore, since `ast.dump` supports an `indent` argument. Here is an example:

```py
>>> import ast
>>> print(ast.dump(ast.parse("print('Hello, world!')"), indent=4))
Module(
    body=[
        Expr(
            value=Call(
                func=Name(id='print', ctx=Load()),
                args=[
                    Constant(value='Hello, world!')],
                keywords=[]))],
    type_ignores=[])
```