# Why 5 <= -15 == 5 >= 1 != 20 is False?

Tags: python, associativity

Can someone tell me why `5 <= -15 == 5 >= 1 != 20` is **False**.

Because when I tried to solve it I did the following:

i) <= , >= have higher priority so it becomes `False == True != 20`

ii) ==,!= have same priority so based on associativity i.e from left to right it becomes `False != 20`

iii) Finally, The answer turns out to be `True`

But, When I tried the same in the python interpreter it returned `False`

I want to understand why that's happening?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: For people looking for operator precedence in python, [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)

Comment: have you tried splitting the problem in smaller peaces to see at which point your explanation does not match the reality?

Comment: You might want to check out the actual [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence): "Note that comparisons, membership tests, and identity tests, all have the same precedence *and have a left-to-right chaining feature as described in the Comparisons section.*"

Comment: @Samathingamajig That page is incomplete and plain wrong, especially for the operators relevant to this question. Please do not link to third-party references unless you make sure they match the actual language reference.

Comment: @Samathingamajig That table doesn't seem to be accurate. Using it gives `True`

Comment: it seems the line results in False == True != 20 and when you assign it to a value, it is resolved from right to left

Comment: It’s `False` because `5 <= -15` is already `False`, and so is `-15 == 5`…

Comment: You can also use `astpretty`  to take a look at the expression tree yourself: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58924031/generating-a-text-representation-of-pythons-ast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's operator precedence is documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence). Contrary to what you claim, all of those comparison operators have the same precedence.

Normally, one looks to associativity to handle ties in precedence. But the comparison operators are special. Python supports [chaining](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons). This means that

```
x relop1 y relop2 z
```

is short for

```
x relop1 y and y relop2 z
```

(Except `y` is only evaluated once.)

So,

```py
    5 <= -15 == 5 >= 1 != 20
=   ( 5 <= -15 ) and ( -15 == 5 ) and ( 5 >= 1 ) and ( 1 != 20 )
=   False and False and True and True
=   False
```

Comment: I find the `and False and True and True` somewhat misleading, as those comparisons don't actually get evaluated.

Comment: @Kelly Bundy, "=" is be taken as "equivalent to"